# Python 2.7 import oddity

Tags: python, python-2.7

I got the following file structure:

```
/sound
    __init.py
    toplevelmain.py
    /filters
        __init__.py
        vocoder.py
    /effects
        __init__.py
        echo.py
    /main
        __init__.py
        x.py
        main.py
    /main2
        __init__.py
        main2.py
```

File Contents are as follows

x.py:

```
def print_x():
    print "X"
```

echo.py:

```
def print_echo():
    print "ECHO"
```

vocoder.py:

```
from effects import echo 
from main import x

def print_vocoder():
    print "VOCODER"
    echo.print_echo()
    x.print_x()
```

toplevelmain.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import filters.vocoder
filters.vocoder.print_vocoder()
```

main.py and main2.py have both the same code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if __package__ is None:
        import sys
        from os import path
        sys.path.append( path.dirname( path.dirname( path.abspath(__file__) ) ) )
        from filters.vocoder import print_vocoder
    else:
        from ..filters.vocoder import print_vocoder
print_vocoder()
```

The Problem:
If I execute toplevelmain.py or main2.py everything works fine. However if I execute main.py which has the same code as main2.py I get the following exception:

```
File "./main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from filters.vocoder import print_vocoder
File "/home/tg/sound/filters/vocoder.py", line 3, in <module>
    from main import x
File "/home/tg/sound/main/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    print_vocoder()
NameError: name 'print_vocoder' is not defined
```

What happens here and how can I alter main2.py in order to keep the file structure?
Is this problem solved in Python 3.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an import loop.

You imported `main.x` in `filters.vocoder`, and imported `filters.vocoder` in `main.main`.

When you are running `main2/main2.py`, there is no import loop. That's why you can run it without error.

You need to update your code to remove one import in the two files.

Comment: Thank you.
Since removing the import loop breaks one executable script, I will just stick to separating library from executables which might be the better way anyway.